# Tornado: How to handle POSTs when using method based routing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I'm using the following handlers, based on finding a project that also uses this style of method-based routing for Tornado:

```
import threading

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.process import cpu_count
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from tornado.escape import recursive_unicode
from tornado.gen import coroutine


class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
        self.io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count())

    @run_on_executor
    def route(self, function, **kwargs):
        threading.currentThread().setName('webUI')
        kwargs = recursive_unicode(kwargs)
        for arg, value in kwargs.items():
            if len(value) == 1:
                kwargs[arg] = value[0]
        return function(**kwargs)


class WebHandler(BaseHandler):

    @coroutine
    def prepare(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = getattr(
                self,
                self.request.path.strip('/').split('/')[::-1][0].replace('.', '_'),
                getattr(self, 'index', None)
            )

        if res:
            view = yield self.route(res, **self.request.arguments)
            self.finish(view)


class Route():

    routes = []


    def __init__(self, uri, name=None):
        self.uri = uri
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, _handler):
        '''Called when routes are decorated'''
        name = self.name and self.name or _handler.__name__
        self.routes.append((self.uri, _handler, name))
        return _handler

    @staticmethod
    def get_routes(webroot='/'):
        try:
            routes = [tornado.web.url(webroot + _uri, _handler, name=name)
                for _uri, _handler, name, in Route.routes]
            routes.reverse()
            return routes
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None

def route_redirect(src, dest, name=None):
    Route.routes.append(tornado.web.url(
        src, tornado.web.RedirectHandler,
        dict(url=dest),
        name=name
    ))
```

Which allows me to do something like the following:

```
@Route('config(/?.*)')
class Config(WebHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Config, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def index(self):
        <do some things and return an index page>

    def general(self):
        <do some thing and return a different page>
```

And thus when a GET is received for /config/, `Config.index()` is run and the index page is returned. Similarly, if I navigate to /config/general, a different page is returned.

However, I am unsure how to handle POST requests now. If I have a form that POSTs to /config/update for example, then when `Config.update()` is executed, it behaves exactly like the other methods for GET requests. The POSTed data is not passed to the method. Further, if I look at the request within either `BaseHandler`, I do not see the POSTed data there either - `request.body` is entirely empty, and trying to call `self.data_received` in the handlers results with the request not be handled at all (the browser will get a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`).

I'm obviously missing something, perhaps quite obvious, but I cannot find any reference to this in the tornado docs, nor anywhere else online as everything revolves around having a separate handler for each page and `get` and `post` methods for each - which is cumbersome and inefficient.

How do I properly handle POSTs when using this style of routing?

Comment: Since you are using monolithic `prepare`, you'll need to check for `self.request.method` in `index()` and handle appropriately.

Comment: you will need to inherit and modify `BaseHandler.route()` actually, since in `prepare()` you call it after returning from `index()` (or have `prepare()` call something else if `self.request.method == 'POST'`.

Comment: and fwiw, I disagree with your assertion about efficiency. I showed the standard tornado dispatch pattern to a Flask developer and he said he prefers that handlers instantiate classes instead of methods, precisely because in a REST context, each route should be implementing all HTTP verbs. The pattern your using is anti-REST, since under REST, you `GET` to `/config` to read `config`, you `POST` to `/config` to create `config`, `PUT` to `/config` to update `config`, and so forth.

Comment: Meant to reply sooner, but you were right about having to modify `BaseHandler.route()`. I capture the POST data there and put it into a dict, and then pass it on. The individual methods, I.E. `Config.general()`, handle both get and post in the same method.